# How to stop the mule application from command line?

Tags: mule

I have Mule `community edition` is installed and how can I stop the one mule application/project which is deployed to Mule server ?

When I did the research, I got the information saying it can be stop only from MMC which comes with enterprise edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A mule application deployed on a mule server can be stopped without MMC.

Go to the "apps" folder of the mule standalone and delete the anchor file for the application you want to stop. Mule will undeploy that application.

Comment: If you copy back the anchor file will it redeploy again ?

Comment: No. You have to copy the mule application zip file into the apps to deploy again.